# How to delete a file with prefix `~$`

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos

I use the command `ls` in a terminal. I found this wired file with the prefix `~$`.
[image]

When I was trying to remove it, the terminal responded `No such file or directory`.
[image]

I even tried renaming it, but it still showed the same error.
[image]

How do I successfully remove or file the file?

Comment: Please copy/paste Terminal content as text, it's much easier to read that way.

Comment: The "weird file" is a temporary file that is created by Word while the original file (which has a similar name without the `~$` prefix) is open. It is supposed to disappear when you close the file.

Comment: @jcaron That's what I expected. However, I didn't open or keep a Word file with the file name.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `filename` contains `$-`, you need to quote the *filename* when using the `rm` *command*, and other *commands*, as the `$-` unquoted is being expanded to a *name* other then the actual *filename* and is why the *file* isn't been found.

**Terminal** *command* examples:

```
% touch '~$-foobar'
% ls ~$-foobar    
zsh: no such user or named directory: 569XZilmsfoobar
% ls '~$-foobar'   
~$-foobar
% rm ~foobar       
zsh: no such user or named directory: foobar
% rm '~$-foobar'   
% 
% ls '~$-foobar'
ls: ~$-foobar: No such file or directory
%
```

Comment: man bash/Special Parameters: "Expands to the current option flags as  specified  upon  invocation,  by  the  set  builtin  command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option)"

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I see @nohillside provided a nice hint so I try to do with this: `rm \~\$-VB6程式.docx`. And it works. The file was removed successfully.